# ng-hide not working once the input field is clicked

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

```
    <md-radio-group ng-model="orderDetails.productType" layout="row">
            <md-radio-button value="paper" class="md-primary"><h4>Paper</h4></md-radio-button>
            <md-radio-button value="nonPaper"><h4>nonPaper</h4></md-radio-button>
    </md-radio-group>

<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-hide="orderDetails.productType === 'paper'" >
    <label>Non-Paper Type</label>
    <input  type="text" name="nonPaperType" ng-required="orderDetails.productType === 'nonPaper'" ng-model="orderDetails.nonPaperType"/>
</md-input-container>
```

I am trying to hide the input container, however, first it works fine, but after clicking on the input it won't hide.

[image: screenshot for issue]

Comment: Can you show how you are changing `orderDetails.productType`?

Comment: Your screenshot shows a input radio, but your code is an input text. There are missing code. Try to improve the question

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/bwEYym)

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-padding>
  <md-radio-group ng-model="orderDetails.productType" layout="row">
      <md-radio-button value="paper" class="md-primary">Paper</md-radio-button>
      <md-radio-button value="nonPaper">Non Paper</md-radio-button>
  </md-radio-group>
  <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-hide="orderDetails.productType === 'paper'" >
    <label>Non-Paper Type</label>
    <input  type="text" name="nonPaperType"  ng-required="orderDetails.productType === 'nonPaper'" ng-model="orderDetails.nonPaperType"/>
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

Comment: same code is not working for me is there a version issue?

Comment: @VictorHanks It's basic AngularJS at work so unless you have really old versions of loaded files it should be okay. Can you edit your answer to show all your markup, especially the radio group?

Comment: added my radio groups

Comment: @VictorHanks Do you see any errors in the console, especially after clicking in the input?

Comment: @VictorHanks Not sure what else to suggest but KrishCdbry's answer may be related somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is an Angular material Issue 
 https://github.com/angular/material/issues/6536

But if you remove the ng-required it should work.

May be this fiddle helps you :

```
`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BLjmZP`
```